# How to search issues in Fabric by user id?

Tags: android, logging, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm using Fabric/Crashlytics in my android app, I use custom logs for logging connections issues and attach user id to log, but how can I search logs for a specific user?

For user id attachment I use `Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(getUserId());` method.
For custon key attachment I use `Crashlytics.setString("error_type", "ConnectionException500");`

I can this id in fabric logs, I can search issues by word in custom keys like search "Connection" and it will return all issues with `ConnectionException500` as custom key, but I cannot understand how to search for a specific user? Like user with id 2332.

I have tried to search `user:2332` and `user=2332` and just `2332` but it shows nothing, and I know there're issues with that specific user (I can see some of them)

Comment: Searching by 2332 should do the trick. If you run the search again, do you see anything returned? Custom keys and user identifiers are searchable as long as the data is at least 4 characters long.

Comment: nope, when I search by 2332 - nothing comes out, more of this, I have user ids less than 4 symbols long (like 1,2 or 3 numbers), I suppose there no way to search them

Comment: For the users < 4 numbers, there isn't a way to search. If you can share your bundle id or package name, I can check on the 2332 issue or if you prefer to share it privately, email into support(at)fabric(dot)io.